# Getting "Can't open the specified file: ......xlsx " while trying to access a file through java XSSFWorkbook

Tags: java

Code to create the workbook :

```
XSSFWorkbook workBook = new    XSSFWorkbook();          
Sheet page = workBook.createSheet("Data");    
workBook.write(new FileOutputStream(new File("/tmp/templates/" +    <randomUUId> + "_Data.xlsx")));
```

Reading the file

```
XSSFWorkbook actualWorkBook = new XSSFWorkbook(new File("/tmp/templates/" +<randomUUID> + "_Data.xlsx"));
```

But the above line throws the following exception:

```
org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidOperationException: Can't open the specified file: '/tmp/templates/65232080-c524-4083-9699-7b7d83f24262_Data.xlsx'
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.<init>(ZipPackage.java:135)
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:257)
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:202)
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:302)
```

Using java11 , spring boot, Apache POI version 3.14